# GNOME Shell interface questions

Tags: 11.10, gnome

Ok, after my upgrade to 11.10 and toying around with the new Unity, I am now trying out GNOME Shell. I really like the dash in GNOME Shell (when you press <kbd>super</kbd>). It feels I can get quick access to anything in my system.

What is not obvious to me:

- how can I add a launcher to my favorites?
- how can I open a second instance of an application from my favorites? (I tried the scroll-wheel click, but it opens a second instance of the application in another workspace)
- is there a list of shortcuts somewhere (as there is for unity)?

I did have a look at the documentation at http://gnome.org, but that was a bit meager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add favourites, right click on the application and select 'Add to favourites'. Alternatively, you can drag them to the launcher. 
[image]

To create an extra instance of the application, right click on the application in the launcher and select 'New Window'.
[image]

For a list of shortcuts, search for 'System settings' and select 'Keyboard'. Click on 'shortcuts' tab and you can see all the shortcuts that are available for use in Gnome-shell.
[image]

Comment: Great answer! However, the last part is a bit misleading - those are shortcuts for GNOME (Unity, GNOME Shell, or GNOME Classic) desktops, not for the Shell itself. He means a "cheat sheet" kind of list, listing all the GNOME Shell specific shortcuts (there is one for Unity here).

Comment: I guess you are right. I did a quick search on Google and reached this [cheatsheet](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet) by the GNOME developers themselves. Seems like a quick overview on most of the shortcuts available in Gnome-shell.

Comment: Add the details of that cheatsheet to your answer for massive rep ;).

Comment: I have just one more question: if I have a launcher for an application I downloaded myself, e.g. some java-program. In Unity I can create a launcher and drag that onto the dash. How do I do that in gnome?

Comment: @nathanvda I think, as long as you can find it in the applications search, you can create a launcher favourite for that application.

Comment: Yes, but that is the problem: I can't find it in the application search. It is an java application I downloaded, placed in a folder, which has an executable file for which I have created a launcher. In Unity I can just drag the launcher onto the dash and done.

Comment: @nathanvda Take a look at this [article](http://blog.randell.ph/2011/08/01/how-to-create-custom-application-launchers-in-gnome-3/). You need to create a desktop shortcut and mark it as an application. And then, search for it and add it to the favourites. :)